# Keeping a tally of how many times a number appears using a random number generator. Java

Tags: java, for-loop, random

In this code I am writing here the user inputs whether or not they would like to choose heads or tails in a coinflip game. I would like to keep a tally of how many times heads appears or tails appears and output it each time it changes. After hours of trying and searching I cannot figure it our perfectly so if someone could let me know what I could utilize let me know.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinToss {


    private enum Coin {
        Head, Tail
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoinToss game = new CoinToss();
        game.startGame();


    }


    private void startGame() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Coin guess;

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter your guess whether the coin will be heads or tails. Type 1 for heads, 2 for tails, or 3 to quit: ");
            String choice = scanner.nextLine();

            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                break;
            } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                guess = Coin.Head;
            } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                guess = Coin.Tail;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please select either heads tails or quit.");
                continue;
            }

            Coin toss = tosscoin();

            if (guess == toss) {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly");
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }


    private Coin tosscoin() {
        
        Random r = new Random();
        int sideup = r.nextInt(2);
        if (sideup == 1) {
            
            return Coin.Head;
        } else {
            return Coin.Tail;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: What about this is not working?

Comment: It is working, sorry if I did not make my question clear. I am attempting to keep a running tally of how many times each side appears as the user continues to choose.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you are doing here seems to mainly expose how are "unrandom" random numbers are on computers from truly random outcomes. The mathematical / statistical "binomial distribution" (aka bell shaped curve) is the true random (non-computer randomized) answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

You can for example add two fields in your CoinToss class. Like **int heads** and **int tails**. Initialize them with 0 in the **startGame()** method. Then, in the **tosscoin()** method:

```
 if (sideup == 1) {
    heads++;
    return Coin.Head;
} else {
    tails++;
    return Coin.Tail;
}
```

You can access these fields in the **startGame()** method and do whatever you want with them.

You could as well define these two variables directly in the **startGame()** method and increment them based on the type of Coin which you get from the **tosscoin()** method.

Comment: Thank you! this put me right on the right track and gave me a good idea on what i needed to do

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work. everytime it tosses, it stores the current value in a variable and compares it next time with the toss value.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinToss {

    private static int headCounter;
    private static int tailCounter;
    private static int previousToss;

    private enum Coin {
        Head, Tail
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoinToss game = new CoinToss();
        game.startGame();


    }


    private void startGame() {
        headCounter = 0;
        tailCounter = 0;
        previousToss = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Coin guess;

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter your guess whether the coin will be heads or tails. Type 1 for heads, 2 for tails, or 3 to quit: ");
            String choice = scanner.nextLine();

            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                break;
            } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                guess = Coin.Head;
            } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                guess = Coin.Tail;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please select either heads tails or quit.");
                continue;
            }

            Coin toss = tosscoin();

            if (guess == toss) {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You guessed incorrectly");
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }


    private Coin tosscoin() {

        Random r = new Random();
        int sideup = r.nextInt(2);
        Coin currentGuess;

        if (sideup == 1) {
            headCounter++;
            currentGuess = Coin.Head;
        } else {
            tailCounter++;
            currentGuess = Coin.Tail;
        }
        checkIfFlipped(sideup);
        return currentGuess;

    }

    static void checkIfFlipped(int currentToss) {
        
        if (currentToss != previousToss) {
            
            if (currentToss == 0) {
                System.out.println("Coin fliped from head to tail");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Coin fliped from tail  to head");
            }
        }

        previousToss = currentToss;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much I was on the right track but not perfectly there, this was perfect guidance.